# Can't run sed command on Bash script

Tags: bash, sed

I'm trying to run the sed command in bash but it keeps giving me errors, I don't know what I did wrong.

This is the code: `$sed 's/unix/linux/' geekfile.txt`
and this is the error message: `bash: s/unix/linux/: No such file or directory.`

I tried adding `-i` and it told me the command is not found. I don't know what to do.
Here is a screenshot of what I am facing:

[image]

Comment: could you provide your example script? make sure not to use eval.

Comment: It's treating your script part of the command `'s/unix/linux'` as a file input which is strange. Is there anything between the `sed` and the `'s/unix/linux'` bit.

Comment: I *suspect* you are including the `$` (which is meant to represent the shell prompt) - this causes the shell to expand `$sed` as a (presumably empty) variable, and then your command is becoming `'s/unix/linux/' geekfile.txt` instead of `sed 's/unix/linux/' geekfile.txt`

Comment: @steeldriver this is definitely what's happening, the screenshot hidden until the suggested edit bears this out.

Comment: @steeldriver that was truly the problem, it works now. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

works fine :

```
user@pc:~$ cat geekfile.txt 
unix 
mal
lala
unix 
oh
user@pc:~$ sed -i 's/unix/linux/' geekfile.txt
user@pc:~$ cat geekfile.txt 
linux 
mal
lala
linux 
oh
```

just don't include the $ sign that's part of the terminal output, not part of the command.